# Netbeans 6.8 download doesn't complete

Tags: netbeans, download, osx-leopard

I'm trying to download the Java bundle of Netbeans 6.8 for Mac OS X and Language=English, [from here](https://netbeans.org/downloads/6.8/), but after a while it just stops coming.

I've tried to download it with iGetter and without iGetter. Does anyone know what the problem could be and how I can get this version of Netbeans?

I've managed to download Netbeans 6.9 from the same page, but unfortunately it doesn't work with JDK 1.5 which is what I can have with my old macbook.

There actually seems to be an issue with Netbeans 6.8 installer as discussed on [this thread](http://forums.netbeans.org/topic20818.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative Netbeans to use with JDK 1.5 would be 6.7.1, since it's almost as good, except that it's better because you can actually download its installer.

The URL is:
https://netbeans.org/community/releases/67/